# Trouble with JSF Filter

Tags: java, jsf

good morning, have a filter in JSF that works well, use it to redirect pages when User session expires. only happens when the session ends, if I click a ajax function, it does not redirect. Like it when the session expires, it redirect to the home page.

My filter tah like this:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    HttpSession session = req.getSession();
    Usuario user = (Usuario) session.getAttribute("usuarioLogado");
    Acesso ac = new Acesso();
    String uri = req.getRequestURI();
    //pegar Browser do usuario
    pegarBrowser(req);
    //verifica se requisição esta dentro do diretorio /telas, se não libera o fluxo
    if (!uri.contains("telas")) {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    } else {
        //verifica se usuario esta logado, e se o diretorio acessado é /telas
        if (session.getAttribute("usuarioLogado") != null && uri.contains("telas")) {
            Long idAcesso = null;
            try {
                idAcesso = user.getAcesso().getId();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
                res.sendRedirect("/erro/expirado.xhtml");
            }

            if (controle == false) {
            }
            try {
                dao = new ViewDAO();
                acDAO = new AcessoDAO();
                role = dao.buscarObjeto("end", uri);
                dao = null;
                ac = acDAO.buscarObjeto("id", idAcesso);
                acDAO = null;

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(filtroAcessoJSF.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

            try {
                String regraURI = role.getGrupo();
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
                String dataHojestring = sdf.format(new Date());
                java.sql.Date dataHoje;
                dataHoje = new java.sql.Date(sdf.parse(dataHojestring).getTime());
                Date limite = user.getDataLimiteAcesso();
                Boolean teste = dataHoje.before(limite);

                if (dataHoje.before(limite)) {
                    if (regraURI.contains(ac.getNome())) {
                        chain.doFilter(request, response);
                    } else {
                        HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
                        res.sendRedirect("/erro/negado.xhtml");
                    }
                } else {

                    if (!uri.equals("/erro/negadoData.xhtml")) {
                        HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
                        res.sendRedirect("/erro/negadoData.xhtml");
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(filtroAcessoJSF.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        } else {
            if (uri.contains("xml.xhtml")) {
                chain.doFilter(request, response);
            }
            HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
            res.sendRedirect("/index.xhtml");
```

lines: res.sendRedirect ("/ index.xhtml");

when the ajax call is for, (I think, not sure) it does not redirects Can anyone help? thank you

Comment: 1) Is `index.xhtml` correct? Why it is not `index.jsf`?  2) Try change sendRedirect to `response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/index.jsf");`

Comment: i change the web.xml to recive files like *.xhtml.